# Visual Studio Code and Unity: VSCode say that namespace already exists

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Here is the thing: I create a new C# Script at the Unity editor and open it on the visual studio. I write my code normally with no errors, it works and I close VSCode.

When I open VSCode again it show some errors saying that the namespace already exists, even thought Unity does not show the same error, and the code keep working properly.

Does anyone have any Idea of what is causing this?

Comment: VSCode does that sometimes if you add/remove plugins or something. I'd close both VSCode and Unity and delete the following list of files/folders: `.vs, Library, obj, Temp`, the `.sln` file and all the `.csproj` files then open the project in unity again, then in VSCode.

Comment: I did that and dosent work. I tried to open a new project and the same thing happens